# What is the segment for Code Blue status in HL7?

Tags: hl7

I am trying to locate in the HL7 Stream for the segment that will provide info on whether code blue: Resuscitation has been performed on a patient. I read online that it is available in the Advanced Directive Observation. Currently I am receiving the ADT, LIS streams. Can I get it from the billing information in ADT?

I am new to HL7 so please help.

Thanks
Dias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every HL7 stream is different. You'll have to ask your source if the information is there and how to find it. Note that the Advanced Directive Observation just tells you whether the patient *has* an advanced directive (like a DNR), not whether any procedure was administered to a patient.

Comment: Thank you, I have some difficulty in talking to my source. Is there an alternative? Also I found by using text search that in the ADT stream the diagnosis information for A08, DG1 diagnosis code I460 gives a resuscitation status for cardiac arrest. Can I use this?

Comment: I've never used DG1 segments, so I don't know how useful they are. Just keep in mind that there are several ADT messages that may contain them, not just A08.